# Copying Map key value from one class to another in Java

Tags: java, class, hashmap, set, maps

Please could anybody help me with copying a Map key value from one class to another in Java.

Example:

```
            public class FirstClass
            {   
               public static Map<String, Integer> firstMethod()
               {
                  Map<String, Integer> firstMap = new HashMap <String, Integer>();
                  firstMap.put("1234", 1000000);
                  firstMap.put("2345", 2000000);
                  firstMap.put("3456", 3000000);
                  firstMap.put("4567", 4000000);
                  return firstMap;
               }   
            }

   public class SecondClass

           public SecondClass()
           {
             instanceSet = new HashSet<ThirdClass>();
           }

      public void addInstance(String string)
       {
         ThirdClass integer = new ThirdClass(string);
         instanceSet.add(integer);     
       }   

       public void someMethod(Map<String, Integer> secondMap)
               {
                  for (ThirdClass instance : instanceSet)
                  {
                     if(secondMap.containsKey(instance.getinstanceNumber()))
                     {
                       //what should go in here??
                     }  
                  }   
               }
```

Essentially, if the instanceSet contains a key that is found in firstMap then how can the Integer value of that key be extracted and copied to the Integer value of the same key in secondMap?

I have looked around online but all of the code examples that I have found don't seem to work presumably because the maps are stored in separate classes.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Could you post a sample input / output?

Comment: I will update the OP now. Thanks.

Comment: Get the firstMap in someMethod of SecondClass as FirstClass.firstMethod()

Comment: I have tried that thanks but the code still refuses to compile.

      public void someMethod(Map<String, Integer> secondMap)
               {
                  for (ThirdClass instance : instanceSet)
                  {
                     if(secondMap.containsKey(instance.getinstanceNumber()))
                     {
                      FirstClass.firstMethod();
                      secondMap.put(instance.getinstanceNumber(), firstMap.get(instance.getinstanceNumber()));
                     }  
                  }   
               }

Error: variable firstMap cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this code. You need the reference of `firstMap` in your `someMethod` or vice versa depending upon from where you want to copy to where.

```
if(secondMap.containsKey(instance.getinstanceNumber())) {
       firstMap.put(instance.getinstanceNumber(), secondMap.get(instance.getinstanceNumber()));
}
```

---

Something like this -

```
public class FirstClass {
    public Map<String, Integer> firstMap;

    public FirstClass() {
        firstMap = new HashMap <String, Integer>();
        firstMap.put("1234", 1000000);
        firstMap.put("2345", 2000000);
        firstMap.put("3456", 3000000);
        firstMap.put("4567", 4000000);
    }

    public void updateMap(String key, Integer value) {
        firstMap.put(key, value);
    }
}

public class SecondClass {

    private Set<ThirdClass> instanceSet;
    private FirstClass firstClass;

    public SecondClass() {
        instanceSet = new HashSet<ThirdClass>();
        firstClass = new FirstClass();
    }

    public void addInstance(String string) {
        ThirdClass integer = new ThirdClass(string);
        instanceSet.add(integer);
    }

    public void someMethod(Map<String, Integer> secondMap) {
        for (ThirdClass instance : instanceSet) {
            if (secondMap.containsKey(instance.getinstanceNumber())) {
                firstClass.updateMap(instance.getinstanceNumber(), secondMap.get(instance.getinstanceNumber()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that SecondClass seems unable to access the map from FirstClass and using dot notation in an attempt to qualify it (e.g. FirstClass.firstMap((instance.getinstanceNumber()) produces a compiler error stating that the firstMap variable cannot be found.

Comment: There is no `FirstClass` which you are using in the `SecondClass`. Not sure what is your `ThirdClass` there. You do not have any `firstMap()` method and you are trying `FirstClass.firstMap((instance.getinstanceNumber())`. The `firstMap` method should exists at class level, you cannot access a local variable of a method outside.

Comment: ThirdClass is another separate class that contains some separate methods and the class type of instance.

So are you saying there is no way for me to copy key values from one map to another if the maps exist in different classes?

Comment: It can be done but you are missing basic understanding of writing java code. Please first learn class, constructor, object, static method, private/public, global/local variable then you will understand what I meant above.

Comment: Thank you and I appreciate your advice and know what most of those things are however this is just a final piece of work that I need to do for a course and then I honestly intend never to dabble with Java ever again (taking the course was a mistake in the first place). If you could just provide some example solution code for this problem then it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I have tried changing the code in the compiler as per your update but unfortunately it still doesn't work and the protocol of Map doesn't seem to include an .updateMap() method.